# Pulling more than 50 results using FTC api in R

Tags: r, api

I'm trying to pull data using FTC's API in R. But the results are limited to only 50 rows. Please advise me on how to get more than 50 from the API.

You can find API details at the following link. https://www.ftc.gov/developer/api/v0/endpoints/do-not-call-dnc-reported-calls-data-api

```
myapikey <- "my-api-key"
URL <- "https://api.ftc.gov/v0/dnc-complaints?api_key=my-api-key"
get.data <- GET(URL, query=list(api_key=myapikey, created_date="2021-01-10"))
ftc.data <- content(get.data) 
jsoncars <- toJSON(ftc.data$data, pretty=TRUE) 
ftc <- fromJSON(jsoncars, flatten = TRUE) %>% data.frame()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the same thing, the page details "Maximum number of records to include in JSON response. By default, the endpoint displays a maximum of 50 records per request – **this is also the maximum value allowed**. All non-empty responses include pagination metadata, which can be used to iterate over a large number of records, by sending a GET request for each page of records." So far I too could not figure out a workaround.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30428611)